# Cannot read property 'send' of undefined discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Does anyone know what's wrong? I am using this line of script -

```
client.on('presenceUpdate', (oldPresence, newPresence) => {
    let member = newPresence.member;
    if (member.id === '603517534720753686') {
        if (oldPresence && oldPresence.status !== newPresence.status) {
            channel = client.channels.cache.get('788547135234375712');
            let text = "";
            if (newPresence.status === "online") {
                text = "**Hello @everyone, Timer Bot is now online! Thank you for your patience.**";
            } else if (newPresence.status === "offline") {
                text = "**@everyone Due to issues, Timer Bot is currently offline. We apologize for the inconvenience.**";
            }
            channel.send(text);
        }
    }
});
```

Every time I run it, my console says -

```
/home/runner/TimerUtilities/index.js:32
            channel.send(text);
                    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
    at Client.<anonymous> (/home/runner/TimerUtilities/index.js:32:21)
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Client.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at PresenceUpdateAction.handle (/home/runner/TimerUtilities/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/PresenceUpdate.js:39:19)
    at Object.module.exports [as PRESENCE_UPDATE] (/home/runner/TimerUtilities/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/PRESENCE_UPDATE.js:4:33)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/home/runner/TimerUtilities/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at Immediate.<anonymous> (/home/runner/TimerUtilities/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:379:14)
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:456:21)
```

It looks like "channel" is unidentified. Does anyone know how to make it identified? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
client.channels.get("ID").send("Your message")
```

Comment: When using it my console says that client.channels.get is not a function. When I use client.channels.cache.get("My-Id").send("My-Message"), it says Cannot read property 'send' of undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Tried doing 'message.channel.send(text)' rather than 'channel.send(text)'?